# CloudFormation nested region

Tags: aws-cloudformation

In a part of the CloudFormation script, how can I add the region name to be taken automatically?

```
"AllowedOrigins" : [
    "http://localhost:5002",
    { "Fn::Join" : ["", ["http://", { "Ref" : "webAppBucketName" } , ".s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com" ]]}
],
```

Instead of the us-east-1

Answer (score 1):

Ok, got it.
You can use `AWS::Region`

```
{ "Fn::Join" : ["", ["http://", { "Ref" : "webAppBucketName" } , { "Fn::Join" : ["", [".s3-website-", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" } , ".amazonaws.com" ]]} ]]}
```